# How to bind a select value to decimal property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Im facing this situation in my aspnet mvc project.

In my view i have:

```
 <form id="testForm">
 <select id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="-1">Less then One</option>
       <option value="1.5" >One and a half</option>
       <option value="2.5" >Two and a half</option>
 </select>
  //other elements
</form> 

     function getResult() {
        $.post("/SomeController/GetResult", $('#testForm').serialize(),  
        function (data)
          { 
             alert('success');
          })
      };
```

Then in my model i have:

```
 public class MyModel
 {
      public decimal Amount{get;set;}
      //other decimal properties
 }
```

I have made a decimal modelbinder and its working for the other decimal values that i have on the same view. The problem is just with the decimal value in the `select` element.

The Amount property doesnt even hit my custom decimal model binder.

Comment: You do not have a `<form>` element with `id="form"`. And why would you need a custom `ModelBinder` for a value which is a valid decimal (or is the server culture one that accepts a different decimal separator?) And what is `datatype="decimal"` - that not a valid attribute of `<option>`?

Comment: What happens if you make your first value `<option value="-1.0">Less then One</option>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ive edited the OP, but it was working i just simplified the code here to illustrate. Actually the mvc has problems to bind decimal numbers so it needs a custom model binder.

Comment: MVC has no problems binding a decimal value - unless you post a format that does not match the culture on the server (e.g you post `1,5` when the server culture expects `1.5` - i.e a culture with a different decimal separator)

Comment: @ChrisF good point, but in the controller the parameters still comes "0M" the default value.

Comment: @ggui, Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTTevI) - select an option, click the button and the controller will return the bound `Amount` value (no custom model binder required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, i figure out the problem, and it was nothing to do with the decimal value. Im using a View Model so i need to put the name of the class before the name of the property, like MyModel.Amount on the name attribute.

Comment: Well your view model should not generally contain properties which are complex objects (so there should be no need to do that anyway) and if you use the strongly typed HtmlHelpers to generate your view then you would never have this problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102480/discussion-between-ggui-and-stephen-muecke).